# Symfony mongoDB oneToMany

Tags: php, database, mongodb, symfony, entity

maybe somehow knows the problem,

I have relation oneToMany, with save/edit all okey

```
    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="RmaWorkerCities", cascade={"all"}, mappedBy="rmaWorker", storeAs="id", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $cities;
   /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="RmaWorkers", inversedBy="cities")
     */
protected $rmaWorker;
```

But when I want to search by cities records I get this error:

```
Cannot use reference \'cities\' in class \'App\\Document\\RmaWorkers\' for lookup or graphLookup: dbRef references are not supported.
```

Or it just doesn't works

What I've tried to do:

```
 $builder = $this->dm->createAggregationBuilder('App\Document\RmaWorkers');

    if (!empty($filters['cityId'])) {
        $builder
            ->lookup('cities')
            ->alias('cities');


        $builder->match()->field('cities.cityId')->equals($filters['cityId']);
    }
```

or just

```
$builder
            ->field('cities.cityId')->equals($filters['cityId'])
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, '*dbRef references are not supported*' on the lookup stage.

A workaround for you would be to extract the objectId from the DBRef, which you could then use normally in your lookup stage.

Written natively, it works like this:

```
db.rmaWorker.aggregate([
{
    $project: { 
        cities_fk: {
          $map: { 
             input: { 
                  $map: {
                      input:"$cities",
                      in: {
                           $arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray: "$$this"}, 1]
                      },
                  }
             },
             in: "$$this.v"}},
        }
}, 
{
    $lookup: {
        from:"cities", 
        localField:"cities_fk",
        foreignField:"_id", 
        as:"B"
    }
])
```

Just adapt the example above to use it with your AggregationBuilder. You can also create a custom function to encapsulate the different steps, so it doesn't clutter your aggregator declaration. Something like :

```
 $builder = $this->dm->createAggregationBuilder('App\Document\RmaWorkers');

if (!empty($filters['cityId'])) {
    $builder
        ->addFields()
        ->name('cities_fk')
        ->mapManyDBRefs()
        ->lookup('cities_fk')
        ->alias('cities');


    $builder->match()->field('cities.cityId')->equals($filters['cityId']);
}
```